# Loop through arguments passed to a method

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, ecmascript-6

I am trying to loop through an argument that is passed to a method and I am getting a `TypeError: individualExpenses.map is not a function`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
class ExpenseTracker {
  constructor(payCheck, monthlyExpenses) {
    this.payCheck = payCheck;
    this.monthlyExpenses = monthlyExpenses;
  }

  storeExpenses(individualExpenses) {
    let expenseStore = [];
    individualExpenses.map(expense => {
      expenseStore.push(expense)
    })
    console.log(expenseStore)
  }
}

const v = new ExpenseTracker({}, {});
v.storeExpenses(1)
```

Comment: [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) must be called on an Array. You are passing a number to the function and that number is what you are trying to call `.map()` on.

Comment: You aren't passing an array to `storeExpenses`. [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: You must pass an array, you could change to `v.storeExpenses([1])`.

Comment: ooooh yeah thanks @ScottMarcus

Comment: If, as it seems from the title, your real intention is to allow any number of arguments to be passed and `push` them all onto `expenseStore`, you should replace the argument `individualExpenses` by `...individualExpenses`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a numerical value to `storeExpenses` function and applying `map` over it. `map` works only on arrays. If you do

```
v.storeExpenses([1]);
```

it'll work just fine.

Alternatively, you can build logic to convert a non-array type to an array and use it in your `storeExpenses` function. This way you can do either of `v.storeExpenses(1)` or `v.storeExpenses([1])` and the function will still work.

e.g.

```
const wrapToArray = (obj) => {
  if (!obj) return [];
  return Array.isArray(obj) ? obj : [obj];
};
```

and then modify your `storeExpenses` method as below -

```
storeExpenses(individualExpenses) {
    let expenseStore = [];
    wrapToArray(individualExpenses).map(expense => {
      expenseStore.push(expense)
    })
    console.log(expenseStore)
  }
```

Comment: yes thanks @Krantisinh, ScottMarcus answered it first so would be unfair to approve this as final answer

Comment: Yup. That's okay :)

Comment: @boomchickawawa That's ok, thanks. I didn't write an "answer", so you can mark this one as "it".

Comment: @Krantisinh this is brilliant, but it would only work if the spread operator is used for the storeExpenses argument, otherwise it would always return just the first element being passed

Comment: @boomchickawawa I guess it'll work without the spread operator also. Tested it in console and seems to work for `storeExpenses(1)` as well as `storeExpenses([1,2,3,4])`

Comment: @Krantisinh I implemented that as a method inside the class and invoked it inside `storeExpenses` method - `this.wrapToArray(individualExpenses)`. Is that what you are doing as well?

Comment: @boomchickawawa Yup. Doing exactly the same.